# How to echo a value from a form in HTML to a table on another page (using PHP)

Tags: php, html, get, request, html-table

I'm trying to echo a value from a HTML form to another page where I have a table, using PHP. Firstly, would I need any code before the table, e.g.

```
<?php
  $_GET[hello.htm]
?>
<table>
```

etc...

Secondly, where would I put the PHP code? Inside each
 `<td></td>` ?

Thirdly, how would the PHP be in order to retrieve the value from say the third box (you can type in them) in the form? Would it be:

```
$_GET[hello.htm,2]?
```

Comment: That looks like you are trying to pass a file in a $_GET, doesn't work like that, you can pass a variable with a value like $_GET['value1'].

Comment: Try var_dump($_REQUEST) to check parameters

Answer (score 2):

1. You need an action that get values as POST type and of course a SUBMIT trigger.
2. PHP codes can be put anywhere.
3. You can get each value from inputs by inputs' IDs or NAMEs.

Comment: For 2. If I already have a table set up, would I not need to put it between the <td> </td> to display it inside the table?

Comment: @J.Extra2 It depends on how you code the page. I would recommend you to create a table inside php codes, but you can just use ajax or even pure javascript to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

you could show all sended values like so:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Then when you know what exactpy you wana show (for example if this is in $_GET superglobal:

```
<?= $_GET['key_name']; ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $_GET['key_name']; ?>
```

For example

```
<form action="other_file.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="my_input_name" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="GO!" />
</form>
```

Will generate

```
$_POST['my_input_name']
```

So you could use it as:

```
<?php echo $_POST['my_input_name']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we need 2 PHP files

1. index.php
2. result.php

## index.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="result.php" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

## result.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h3> Result: </h3>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td> Name </td>
                <td> Email </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $_POST["email"] ?> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

> - in index.php we use form `action` to send data to result.php
> - in result.php we use `$_POST['form_input_name']` to get data from form input